# Проверка ssl сертификата посредством JS — как обойти при необходимости использовать MITM?

Tags: javascript, ssl

Ситуация. Есть свой прокси, умеющий в логирование `har`, которое мне необходимо для работы. Для этого я использую один из вариантов прокси, умеющий в `MITM`. Плюс устанавливаю его сертификат корневым в браузере, чтобы последний не ругался на незащищенное соединение. При этом, есть сайты, где, как я понимаю, есть проверка сертификатов на уровне `javascript`. Насколько я понимаю, они таким образом дополнительно защищаются от фрода.

И вот тут возникает проблема - данные сайты не пускают меня, реального человека, к себе, так как видимо считают, что мой браузер скомпрометирован, видя какие-то проблемы с сертификатом. Вопрос - как мне обойти это все? Есть ли вообще возможность сделать это, не потеряв возможности логировать запросы к защищенным сайтам на уровне прокси?

Comment: Проверка не на JS, а просто SSL Pinning

Comment: @AlexeyTen нет-нет, проверка идет именно средствами JS. Да и HTTP public key pinning перестал поддерживаться тем же Хромом еще в том году.

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте установить mitmpproxy (наиболее проще и нагляднее всего, встанет даже на win без проблем), указать в настройках системы 127.0.0.1:8080 как адрес прокси и попробовать зайти на сайт Связного. Будет постоянный редирект (если у них будет на текущий момент защита включена).